# Computing hyperdeterminant of n-dimensional squared Tensor

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

For the purpose of computing the [generalized variance](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/60072/generalized-variance) of a Tensor with shape `(n, n, n, ...., n)` I want to compute the [hyperdeterminant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperdeterminant) of the [covariance of a Tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_of_vectors), obtained using [tfp.stats.covariance](https://www.tensorflow.org/probability/api_docs/python/tfp/stats/covariance).

Suppose you have a Tensor `T` (*the following syntax works on [Tensorflow 2.0](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/effective_tf2))*:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

T = tf.constant(np.random.random(size=(1000, 100, 100)))
```

The shape of the obtained tensor is `(1000, 100, 100)`.

To determine its covariance we use [tfp.stats.covariance](https://www.tensorflow.org/probability/api_docs/python/tfp/stats/covariance):

```py
import tensorflow_probability as tfp

@tf.function() # To evaluate graph.
def covariance(T):
    return tfp.stats.covariance(T)

cov = covariance(T)
```

The obtained tensor `cov` has shape `(100, 100, 100)`. I would love now to compute its hyperdeterminant, but the implementation present in TensorFlow [tf.linalg.det](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/linalg/det) is defined on vectors of shape `(n, m, m)` of squared matrices of shape `(m, m)` and therefore computes `m` determinants, one for each matrix.

```py
@tf.function() # To evaluate graph.
def determinant(T):
    return tf.linalg.det(T)

det = determinant(cov)
```

The obtained Tensor det has shape `(100,)`.

How do I obtain a scalar hyperdeterminant for any given hyper-cubic Tensor with shape `(n, n, n, ..., n)`?

Thanks!

**References**

Since there's little to no material on the subject of hyperdeterminant of hypercubes, I list here some of the seminal papers on the matter:

- [Discriminants, Resultants, and Multidimensional Determinants](https://www.amazon.it/Discriminants-Resultants-Multidimensional-Determinants-2008-04-16/dp/B01FIZ03A8/ref=sr_1_2?__mk_it_IT=%C3%85M%C3%85%C5%BD%C3%95%C3%91&keywords=discriminants%2C+resultants%2C+and+multidimensionale+determinants&qid=1571257269&sr=8-2)
- [Hankel Hyperdeterminants](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math-ph/0211044.pdf)
- [Memoire sur le Hyperdeterminants](https://books.google.it/books?id=GAVCAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA7&lpg=PA7&dq=memoire+sur+les+hyperdeterminant&source=bl&ots=qocluKfDfo&sig=ACfU3U3t7OvUyc77d3b4SgtQ1mGFXaJXfA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjvo-bfx6HlAhUPGewKHZlhBI0Q6AEwBXoECAYQAQ#v=onepage&q=memoire%20sur%20les%20hyperdeterminant&f=false)
- [Collected papers of Arthur Cayley](https://ia802205.us.archive.org/18/items/collectedmathem01caylgoog/collectedmathem01caylgoog.pdf)

Comment: hey  @Luca, just a question not an answer(sorry). Is computing a hyperdeterminant analogous to computing the 'determinant of a determinant'?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, it should be a different formalism, but I'm really still learning its definition. I'm sifting through old papers to get an "easy" definition to build upon. Currently I'm trying to [understand if this library is correct and what it is based upon](https://github.com/gnang/HypermatrixAlgebraPackage/blob/master/Hypermatrix_Algebra_Package_code.sage).